# Magento2 extending class in a custom module conflicts with other module extending the same class

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have created a Custom Module to override the Image sizing on upload.

In my block I have the class, which extends like:

```
namespace Myweb\ImageResize\Block\Media;

class Uploader extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget
{
 protected $_template = 'Myweb_ImageResize::media/uploader.phtml';
```

but there is another Module I am using from Ced Commerece which also extending the same class

```
namespace Ced\CsProduct\Block\Helper\Form\Gallery;

class Content extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget
{
 protected $_template = 'Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml';
```

Now when using upload widget in admin in default backend, it works fine, but when I am using the Ced Panel for vendor

I am getting the error like:

```
Invalid template file: 
'ImaginationMedia_ImageProccess::media/uploader.phtml' in module: 
'ImaginationMedia_ImageProccess' block's name: 'gallery_schedule_block0.uploader'
```

How I can overcome this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue.
If you want to override below template file

> protected $_template =
>   'Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml';

with your custom module then you can write with your custom path otherwise it will call Magento Catalog template by default.
No need to write this line:

> protected $_template =
>   'Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml';

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and found out that ***Amasty_AdminActionsLog*** was causing the issue. for now, we have disabled the module